# Wie sage ich "used to do" auf Deutsch?

Tags: english-to-german, verb, past

Wie übersetzt man "used to do s.th." ins Deutsche? Ich habe früher etwas regelmäßig getan, was ich jetzt nicht mehr tue. Gibt es eine bestimmte Verbform im Deutschen, die das ausdrückt?

Comment: Ein wichtiges Wort hast Du bereits gefunden, nämlich "früher". Ein Beispiel: `Früher habe ich Kaffee zum Frühstück getrunken, heute nicht mehr`. Früher + Perfekt zeigt an, dass Du etwas gewohnheitsmäßig (= regelmäßig) getan hast. Es gibt sicher noch ein Dutzend weitere, verschiedene Möglichkeiten, um das auf Deutsch zu sagen, was das Modalverb "used to" auf Englisch sagt.

Comment: Das ist doch im Prinzip auch schon die Antwort. Das einzige, was mir noch einfällt, ist, dass man oft das Wort "immer" benutzt. "Früher hab' ich immer Kaffee zum Frühstück getrunken..."

Comment: @Emanuel Eigentlich habe ich genau auf Dich gezählt, dass Du eine "amtliche" Antwort gibst :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ein schönes klassisches Wort für 'used to do sth.' ist ja auch '**pflegte**' (von pflegen), das mit '**Gepflogenheit**' verwandt ist. In der alltäglichen Umgangssprache hört man es seltener, aber z.B. bei Vorträgen und im Schriftsprachlichen ist es durchaus lebendig.

> • Sie pflegte ihren Kaffee schwarz zu trinken.
>
> • Ich pflegte damals, mit dem Mountainbike durch die Stadt zu
> rasen.
> • Beim Aufräumen fand ich die hässliche Krawatte, die
> meine  Schwiegermutter mir geschenkt hatte und die ich ihr zuliebe
> anzulegen pflegte, wenn wir bei ihr zum Kaffee eingeladen waren.
>
> • Er pflegte zum Ende seiner Arbeitsschicht hundemüde zu sein.

Siehe auch Digitales Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache: http://www.dwds.de/?qu=pflegen&view=1

Comment: Yes, this is also very much the Yiddish expression for "used to". It's funny that such a useful word would seem to have largely disappeared from the spoken language.

Comment: Er pflegte kranke Tiere zu verspeisen.

Answer (score 8):

[TehMacDawg's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/6345/44) is correct ("pflegen") , but in colloquial language you won't hear it very often.

You could use *immer* and say:

> Sie hat ihren Kaffee immer schwarz getrunken.
>
> Damals raste ich immer mit dem Mountainbike durch die Stadt.
>
> etc.

Sounds more natural to me.

Comment: `Used to` ist aber eine Relativierung, während `immer` eine Bekräftigung ist.

Comment: @userunknown vielleicht ist "früher [in der Vergangenheit] immer" besser? *Sie hat ihren Kaffee früher immer schwarz getrunken.*

Comment: Womöglich hat sie ihren Kaffee jedoch nur meist schwarz getrunken. Aus "used to drink" würde ich kein "immer" ableiten.