# How to use the verb "pflegen" with the meaning of - being used to do something?

Tags: verb, vocabulary

How to use the verb "pflegen" with the meaning of - be used to doing something?

Example - How to say

> My grandmother is used to taking a nap every afternoon.

Comment: This meaning of "pflegen" isn't used much anymore. If you want to use it anyway, look at Ingmar's answer, otherwise just say "Meine Oma macht jeden Tag ein Mittagsschläfchen."

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9444/used-to-verb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb 'pflegen' can be translated as 'used to do sth.' but not as 'getting used to do sth.'. It's meant to be used on repeating tasks or habits.

Synonym: gewohnt sein

**Examples:**

Past:

> My granny used to take a nap every afternoon
>
> Meine Oma pflegte jeden Nachmittag ein Schläfchen zu machen.
>
> Meine Oma war es gewohnt jeden Nachmittag ein Schläfchen zu machen.

Present:

> My granny is used to take a nap every afternoon
>
> Meine Oma pflegt jeden Nachmittag ein Schläfchen zu machen.
>
> Meine Oma ist es gewohnt jeden Nachmittag ein Schläfchen zu machen.

.

**'getting used to do sth.':**

Notice: In contrast to 'pflegen', the synonym 'gewohnt sein' can be used as 'getting used to do sth.':

> She is getting used to take a nap every afternoon.
>
> Sie gewöhnt sich an die Schläfchen jeden Nachmittag.

.

**Other meanings of pflegen:**

'pflegen' is mostly used as caring for sth./sb. but only in a positive context:

> He is taking care of his car
>
> Er pflegt sein Auto.

In a negative context (example: killing sb.) the synonym 'kümmern' has to be used:

> He is taking care of his boss.
>
> Er kümmert sich um seinen Boss.

Answer (score 8):

pflegen zu + inf., e.g.

> Meine Großmutter pflegt jeden Nachmittag ein Mittagsschläfchen zu machen.

Comment: Emanuel is right in his answer that "pflegen" is not the correct translation for "to be used to (doing) sth". The meanings are totally difference. There's a difference between "to be/get used to" and "used to do sth". While the latter is indeed a good fit for "pflegen", the former–as applied in OP's question–is not. I'm afraid, in respect to that your translation/answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The English sentences as it stands cannot be translated with "pflegen". It means that your grandmother is habituated to doing that.
"Pflegen" in present tense translates roughly to "to have the habit of/ to have something as a custom".

> Ich pflege zu gähnen, wenn mich was langweilt.
>   I usually yawn, if something bores me.

In past tense, it can be translated as the English "used to do something".

> Ich pflegte viel zu gähnen.
>   I used to yawn a lot.

Comment: I agree with you. The sense of "to be used to" does indeed not concur with the German "pflegen etw. zu tun" and is thus a wrong translation. What's missing in your answer, though, is a recommendation of what to use instead for "to be used to".

Comment: @Em1... I don't think OP wants to know that but feel free to add it. I have a feeling however, that we've had a question like this a few months ago

Comment: @Em1... just saw that you have your head in the ring. So never mind about the adding :)

Answer (score 0):

As [Emanuel correctly points out](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/12364/1224), "to be used to" is **not** translated with *pflegen*.

Not sure what your mother tongue is, but for non-natives the English "used to do sth" and "to be/get used to (doing) sth" might be very confusing.

"Used to do sth" would be correctly translated with *pflegen* but it refers to an usual task in the past.

"To be/get used to (doing) sth", in contrast, means to be/get familiar with something.

Thus, I suggest the following translation:

> My grandmother is used to taking a nap every afternoon.
> Meine Großmutter ist es gewohnt, jeden Nachmittag ein Nickerchen zu machen.
>
> My grandmother used to take a nap every afternoon.
> Meine Großmutter pflegte jeden Nachmittag ein Nickerchen zu machen.