# Wie sagt man „They used to live in XXX for a long time“ auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, verb

Wie sagt man „They lived in XXX for a long time“ auf Deutsch, nach „die sind an einen anderen Ort umgezogen“?

- Sie sind in XXX lang gelebt
- Sie haben in XXX lang gelebt
- Sie lebten in XXX während lang
- Sie sind in XXX lang gewohnt
- Sie haben in XXX lang gewohnt
- Vor langer Zeit haben sie in XXX gelebt
- Vor langer Zeit wohnten sie in XXX

Ich finde keine Lösung, die gut klingt … Alle klingen sehr schlecht.

Comment: Substantive werden auf Deutsch groß geschrieben (*Zeit, Lösung* etc.). Es muss wegen starker Beugung *vor lange**r** Zeit* heißen. Da diese Fehler (wie auch *an einen Ort umziehen*) den Kern der Frage nicht betreffen, habe ich sie korrigiert.

Comment: [Linguee](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=they+used+to+live) bietet bei solchen Fragen übrigens oft sehr gute Übersetzungsvorschläge an.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sowohl *leben* als auch *wohnen* sind Verben, die ihr Perfekt mit *haben* bilden. Demnach sind einige Vorschläge aus deiner Liste falsch.

Auch *vor langer Zeit* bedeutet nicht, was du ausdrücken möchtest. Statt *for a long time* ist die korrekte Übersetzung *a long time ago* – ein Falscher Freund.

Das Adverb zum Adjektiv *lang* ist *lange.*

Mit all diesen Punkten im Hinterkopf ist klar, dass du eigentlich nur noch einen Satz ein wenig umstellen musst:

> Sie haben lange in XXX gewohnt.
>
> Sie haben lange in XXX gelebt.

Die beiden Verben sind zwar nicht identisch aber ähnlich genug, sodass beide hier möglich sind. Wenn ich wählen müsste, würde ich *gewohnt* sagen, wenn es hauptsächlich ums Wohnen geht (aber Arbeit, Schule, Einkaufen, Ausgehen woanders stattgefunden hat), und *gelebt* wenn sich auch der Großteil des Lebens dort abgespielt hat.

Gegebenenfalls sollte statt des Perfekts Präteritum gewählt werden; das gilt umso mehr je nördlicher in Deutschland, je schriftlicher und je förmlicher die Kommunikation. Diese Fälle wären dann:

> Sie lebten lange in XXX.
>
> Sie wohnten lange in XXX.

Comment: Gelebt oder gewohnt: ich würde "gelebt" zB auch bei Ländern verwenden: Sie haben in den USA gelebt. Aber: Sie haben in Köln gewohnt.

Comment: statt *lange* kann man auch *(eine) lange Zeit* verwenden, um die Dauer auszudrücken

Answer (score 2):

> Sie lebten einmal/einst/früher lange Zeit in XY.
>
> Einst/Früher lebten sie lange Zeit in XY.

Mögliche Übersetzungen des Ausdrucks "used to" wurden hier auch schonmal angefragt:

["used to [verb]"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9444/used-to-verb)

[Wie sage ich "used to do" auf Deutsch?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6342/wie-sage-ich-used-to-do-auf-deutsch)

Answer (score 1):

Wie wäre es mit "Sie haben lange in xxx gelebt" oder "Sie haben für eine lange Zeit in xxx gelebt"?

"Sie sind in xxx lang gelebt" ist grammatikalisch/semantisch falsch.

"Sie haben in xxx lang gelebt" da ist der Focus aber eher auf dem leben als auf der Zeit wie in: "They lived in xxx for a long time". Ist als Übersetztung aber richtig.

"Sie lebten in xxx während lang" ist grammatikalisch falsch.

"Sie sind in xxx lang gewohnt" grammatikalisch falsch.

"Vor langer Zeit haben sie in xxx gelebt"* ist semantisch falsch da es in 
"They lived in xxx for a long time" nicht darum geht, wann sie dort gelebt haben, sondern wie lange sie dort gelebt haben. Im Englischen wäre * also : "Long ago they lived in xxx".

"Vor langer Zeit wohnten sie in xxx"** siehe im Absatz ein vorne dran und im englischen wäre ** : "Long ago they did live in xxx"